# Android Studio showing error while creating a Jetpack Compose project

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a Compose Project using Android Studio IDE.
But after execution of gradle build it shows a error:-

Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.LanguageVersion'.

I am trying to solve this from two days but didn't find any solution.

Comment: Please check this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19955/IDE-Gradle-66-ClassNotFoundException-orgjetbrainskotlinconfigLanguageVersion-on-project-import#focus=Comments-27-5347085.0-0